# Why combo box is not getting hide on page load?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to hide the combobox on page load. The combobox has not getting hide. I can't find any error on webbrowser's inspect element. I've checked the select tag syntax and javascript all are seems fine. But its not getting hide?

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 
$list=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from emp");
echo "<select id='dropbx'>";
echo "<option value=''>emp Code</option>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list))
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['emp_code'] . "'>" . $row['emp_code'] . "</option>"; //Why Two column mentioned??
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() 
{
    document.getElementById('dropbx').visibility = "hidden";
    //alert('hello');
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the code like this. `visibility` is the property of the style `attribute` of the element. You can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp

```
document.getElementById("dropbx").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: Hi @devesh Thanks. Its working. Instead you answer, i've tried that `document.getElementById("dropbx").style.display = "hidden";` .Its not working...

Comment: @user6161 i think in case of display you have to us "none" check this https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 3):

you can hide dropdown by using `hide()` like this :

```
$("#dropbx").hide();
```

or you can use `display` property like this :

```
    document.getElementById("dropbx").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: yes then have to use second option by using style.display = "none"

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to do it in server side.

```
echo "<select id='dropbx' style='display:none;'>";
```

**or** (if you don't want inline styles)

```
echo "<select id='dropbx' class='hidden'>";
```

in your css

```
.hidden {
   display:none;
}
```